# Jquery Range Slider - Select Range outside min and max value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a jquery range slider to select a range of hourly values. The slider has a min value of 0 (12am) and a max value of 24 (12am).

Sometimes I would like to select a range that goes overnight (i.e. 19:00 - 3:00). This is the opposite of what the slider is configured to do. Selecting this range would typically result in a selection of 3:00 - 19:00 rather than the opposite.

Ideally I could drag one of the handles through the other to change the way the range is selected.

My slider values come from the slider event below

```
$("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + ":00 - " + ui.values[1] + ":00");
```

Any suggestions on how to build a slider with this functionality?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDM7U/) where I have a slider setup for a 0-24 time period.

Comment: In that case you would probably have to build your own..  Which would be quite the undertaking, or find another plugin that would do it for you, I took a look at a number of sliders but could not find this functionality.

Comment: From previous answer http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/MNZhR/

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. I guess I could just have 2 sliders for the min and max time.